# Close network kernel socket

Tags: macos, sockets, bsd, kernel-extension

I'm developing a network kernel extension and tried to intercept packets, on DataOut callback returned `EJUSTRETURN` to swallow desired packets. Now I'm willing to pass out same data but on different socket. To achieve this I used

```
    errno_t errorRet = 0;
    socket_t newSocket;

    errorRet = sock_socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, sockectUpCallBack, cookie, &newSocket);
    errorRet = sock_bind(newSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&localAddress);
    errorRet = sock_connect(newSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&remoteAddress, MSG_DONTWAIT);
```

This thing is working and `connect` function return with code `EINPROGRESS  36      /* Operation now in progress */`. Now my question is, is it possible to close the socket the packet previously sent through?

Comment: Packets don't bind to sockets. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry for that, i meant to say that the socket used to deliver the packet on network.

Comment: Supoose you clarify the text in your question, instead of just adding to the confusion.

Comment: Yep, it's still not clear what exactly the question is here. Maybe provide some example code of what you think you want to do?